# what kind of circuit structure can I use to obtain high output impedance?

Tags: impedance, impedance-matching, high-impedance

what kind of circuit structure can I use to obtain high output impedance?
In my design I need an amplifier whose output impedance is extremely high,which structure can do this? I read in Sansen's *Analog Design Essentials* that a cascode circuit will do, but I don't know how to bias it. So would you kindly show me the complete circuit?
[image: Sansen's book]

in fact I am designing a circuit like this:there is a block whose impedance have been matched,but I need a block in series with it, so I need the new block to have high impedance.
[image]

Comment: That's strange can you say why you need high output impedance?  I mean a silly thought is to just stick a large value resistor in series with your output.

Comment: "high output impedance" - how high?

Comment: High output impedance for what specific job? A large value resistor will do, but not if you need high power, or high bandwidth. Specifications please.

Comment: Nobody wants high output impedance. That is why you are getting these comments. You want a high impedance load on the collector or drain to maximize gain, right? Use a current source as a load. If you really do want high output impedance, just put a resistor in series with the output. Are you sure you need cascode? You should simulate with and without to see if you need it.

Comment: thank you all. I add some new information about the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The biasing of a cascode is very simple ! You just apply a DC voltage to the gate of the cascoded transistor. Note that in your picture this is also the case although the gates are grounded. For small signal: Grounded = A DC voltage, remember ? Note that the cascode is a common-gate amplifier. It has current input and output.

Here's an example: M1 is the cascode, it only "buffers" the current coming out of M2 which is a common source amplifier. In this configuration M2 will be a happy NMOS since it's Vds will be almost constant. This gets rid of much of the influence of the Rout of M2. There is of course still the Rout of M1 but that does not matter as M2 determines the current, not the cascode M1 !

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSh7Zw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>